# What are Uruk motives for?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

In **Middle Earth: Shadow of Mordor**, Uruk captains have motives. What are these motives for? What can the player do with them? Are they just flavour text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Motives are just flavor text. Any of the Uruk captains' strengths and vulnerabilities are explicitly listed.

Comment: Well that's a disappointing. I thought I could play around with those. Thanks!